# Prove that : $\sqrt C_1+\sqrt C_2 +\sqrt C_3 \ ... +\sqrt C_n \leq \sqrt{n(2^n-1)}$

Tags: summation, binomial-coefficients

If $ C_0, C_1 , C_2, ... , C_n$ are the combinatorial coefficients in the expansion of $(1 +x)^n$,
$n\in N$, then prove the following :$$\sqrt C_1+\sqrt C_2 +\sqrt C_3 \ ... +\sqrt C_n \leq \sqrt{n(2^n-1)}$$
By the appearance of the problem it seems that sum inequality property of roots must be applied. As I observe that $2^n-1$ is $C_1+C_2+C_3+...+C_n $. Also it will be helpful for me in future if such link or list useful properties compiled together is provided.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Since $x\mapsto\sqrt{x}$ is a concave function, for non-negative $x_1,\cdots, x_n$ it holds [Jensen's inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jensen's_inequality#Finite_form) $$\frac{\sqrt{x_1}+\cdots+\sqrt{x_n}}{n}\le\sqrt{\frac{x_1+\cdots+x_n}{n}}$$

Hence $$\sqrt{x_1}+\cdots+\sqrt{x_n}\le\sqrt{n(x_1+\cdots+x_n)}$$

As you noticed, now you only have to substitute $x_k=\binom{n}{k}$ and it's exactly your inequality.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: arithmetic mean is at most the quadratic mean.

Answer (score 0):

Hint $\sqrt{C_1}=\sqrt{C_{n-1}}$ so lhs is 2$\sum\sqrt{C_i}$ where i runs from $1$ to $n/2$ or $(n-1)/2$ odd,even $n$ and rhs simplifies to $\sqrt{2n{\sum {C_i}}}$ which in any case by observation is greater than or equal to lhs.